# Upgrade database in DBFlow Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dbflow

We released a version of the application in Play Store which implemented DBFlow, now we wants to update the app into next version, in that we should add two new tables to the existing database using DBFlow. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add any migrations for new tables, DBFlow creates them automatically. Just increase your DB version.

Comment: Honestly, this does not work with DBFlow on my project, i increased the version to no avail.